# store 2 different objects in array

Tags: java

How do i store 2 different objects in array? So when i have for example object Worker ("name","age",Payroll) then another object that is Computer ("price","specification","..."). And I store these objects in a class.

```
class Record
{
  top = -1;
  private Worker array_w[];
  private Computer array_c[];
```

But then i have to do this:

```
 public void insert(Worker number) {
    if ((top + 1) < array_w.length)
     { top += 1; array_w[top] = number; }

 public void insert(Computer number) {
    if ((top + 1) < array_c.length)
     { top += 1; array_c[top] = number; }
 }
```

to insert each object into the new class.

How do I make it so there is only one array that stores any object.

Comment: I suppose you could have an array of `object`, but I wouldn't recommend it. It's not really a good idea to be mixing two different objects that, on the surface, don't appear to have any affiliation with each other.

Comment: Just as a note, the arrays won't automatically grow when you add to the array at index `top + 1` unless you have declared the array with extra space (in which case you would have to keep track). You may want to consider using an ArrayList or similar data structure to add/remove items on demand.

Comment: Well I want to print every object from class Record. And I'm having trouble printing it right now because there are two arrays, but when i had only one object type(Worker) I had one array and the program worked. So I'm trying to have only one array. It is also less code, because i don't have to type everything twice.

Comment: @Daniel it's not exactly a lot of work to print two arrays (as long as there are only two ;)). I feel like the benefits of having two arrays is greater overall even though it might result in having (slightly) more code for printing them.

Comment: Since you mentioned you want to print them, use the answer you choose and look at the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Thank you. It's working great now. Visitor Pattern helped too. Interface was really helpful and the best is that I'm using only one array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would advise against mixing Objects, but if you must have one array, there are a few things you could do:

Have both objects inherit the same Object, or Implement the same interface:

```
public class Worker extends MyMainClass
public class Computer extends MyMainClass
```

OR

```
public class Worker implements IMyInterface
public class Computer implements IMyInterface
```

You then have:

```
MyMainClass[] myArray;
```

OR

```
IMyInterface[] myArray;
```

(Preferably the interface)

Alternatively, if the Worker and Computer go hand in hand, write a Wrapper and insert both in the same index.

```
public class Wrapper {
    private Worker worker;
    private Computer computer;
    ...
}

public void insert(Wrapper wrapper) {
    ...
}
```

And then you have an array:

```
Wrapper[] myArray;
```

Comment: Probably best to use a Collection rather than an Array[].

Comment: I'm trying to use the interface. But I'm not sure how to create the array in class Record.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good design but if you wanted to then what you could do is have

First create an interface :

```
public interface MarkerInterface {
    public String print();
}
```

Then use that to implement both classes

```
public class Worker implements MarkerInterface {
   ...
   @Override 
   public String print() {
       return "worker class what ever you want to print"
   }
}

public class Computer implements MarkerInterface {
   ...
   @Override 
   public String print() {
       return "computer class what ever you want to print"
   }
}
```

Now create an array in Record class

```
public class Record
{
    MarkerInterface[] objects = new MarkerInterface[10];
    ...
}
```

Now you can instantiated the array of type MarkerInterface and store both of them.

Remember  when you want to use the object from array you need to do

```
if(obj isinstanceof Computer) {...} else if(obj isinstanceof Worker) {...}
```

or if the method is defined in the interface then you can simply do

```
System.out.println(obj.print());
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have a common interface or class above Computer and Worker class. If that's the case, you could do something like:

```
 MyTopInterface[] array = ..
```

Now you could just use same array and populate either worker or computer objects in it.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use an array of Object or a shared base class

```
 private Object [] data;
```

but then you'd have `instanceof Computer` and `instanceof Worker` all over the place. And think of "how many Computers per Worker are there?" - simple division vs. loop-and-count.

My advice: keep separate members. Maybe `List <Computer>` instead of array even.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all of the other excellent (in some cases) suggestions you could always create a mashup class that can hold either of two types.

```
class OneOf<A, B> {

    A a;
    B b;

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public OneOf setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = null;
        return this;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public OneOf setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
        this.a = null;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a != null ? Objects.toString(a) : Objects.toString(b);
    }

}
```